# JVM Generational Spacing

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, java

Using the following options in OpenJDK 1.6, I end up with 600mb eden, 2mb survivor, and 3gb tenured (from JConsole). I'm just messing with settings trying to figure out why the JVM won't allocate memory the way I want it to.

This application needs to lean heavier on the Eden than the Tenured.

JAVA_OPTS="-Duser.timezone=US/Eastern -Xms6000m -Xmx8000m -Xmn3000m -XX:SurvivorRatio=1 -XX:MaxPermSize=1500m -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=200m -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=35 -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:/var/log/tomcat6/gc.log -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=100M -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintPromotionFailure -XX:PrintFLSStatistics=1 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8090 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"

My expectation based on reading is that I would have 6000mb in the heap to start, 8000mb max. 3000mb would be given to new gen, and the survivor ratio would put eden memory : survivor at 1500mb : 1500mb. That is clearly not what I'm seeing in JConsole (above).

Can someone provide some insight as to why the flags I have would show the eden / survivor / tenured in JConsole the way they do vs the way I expect? I have been pouring over JVM documentation for a while and this does not seem like the behavior in the documentation.

Thanks so much in advance for the input!

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Post edited

Comment: The minimum heap is the point at which the JVM makes little attempt to clean up memory i.e. a Hello World program doesn't use 6000m.  BTW 6000m != 6G.  Without more explanation of what you are seeing it would be impossible to explain what it is.